# SSRS comparing Current Row to Previous Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have the following Expression in a field in SSRS:

```
=iif(Fields!Score.Value > Previous(Fields!Score.Value),"Greater","Less Than")
```

I have the following Scores in my scenario across 4 rows:

```
3 
3 
4 
5
```

It results in:

```
3 - Greater
3 - Less Than
4 - Greater
5 - Greater
```

The issue is with the first row always being Greater. It should be blank because there isn't a previous row to compare against. I would expect the results to be as follows:

```
3 - 
3 - Same
4 - Greater
5 - Greater
```

How could I change the above formula to produce the above result?

The above is an example of only one row group. There are then further row groups with different Scores, so the different results of Same/Greater/Less Than need to work across the different row groups.

Comment: You need to see if they are equal to get the "Same" message. Also if you check the Previous value, is it null if you are on the first row. Maybe just added to the report for testing, so you can see what is in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following:

```
=IIF(RowNumber(NOTHING)=1,"",IIF(Fields!Score.Value = Previous(Fields!Score.Value),"Same",IIF(Fields!Score.Value > Previous(Fields!Score.Value),"Greater","Less Than")))
```

modified. try now.

Comment: Thanks @Viking - that nearly worked. It is showing the  following now:
3 - (blank)
3 - Less Than
4 - Greater
5 - Greater
The only mistake there is that Less Than should be replaced with Same because 3 matches 3.

Comment: would appreciate if you can post what you are getting so that I can visualize and can solve? thanks :)

Comment: just noticed that u r not even using same option in ur expression. please edit expression to use that.

Comment: That's a part of what I'm struggling with is to get "Same" included in the expression when the current row matches the previous row.

Comment: I've modified it. try now.

Comment: Thanks Viking, That is working for the first grouping within the SSRS report now, but for the other first rows in the different sets, it isn't. I assume this is something to do with (RowNumber(NOTHING)=1. Is it possible to turn that into something different to pick up each individual "Row Group" in SSRS?

Comment: Man.. it's a moving target. May be you need to revise your question to reflect all what you want with field names or dataset image and desired output image. It will then give me better idea that what to suggest.

Comment: Sorry about that, didn't realise the function wouldn't work across different row groups.

Comment: Thanks for that, I modified the underlying query to pickup the Row Number and changed that part of your expression.